# How does django generate unique user token

Tags: django

I'm a bit confused about token authentication. After a few question and attempts I've manage to create `url` gateway for auto-login my users but I'm managing to do that only by using `user_id` and passing it out in the `url` for example `http://example.com/auth/login/?user_id=12` but I would rather do it with `?token=`.

I'm using [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) example on how make custom auth token and return some more data about my user with that so after I curl to the `url` I'm returning

`{"token":"d5d86e55fd5ddd48298b2ac72c3ed96b7e30dd86","user_id":52}`

Now the problem that I'm facing is this [MyUser maching query does not exists](http://dpaste.com/2TG5XS0) which is normal I didn't have token in my model so I've created one

`token = models.CharField(max_length=125, null=True, blank=True)`

so I could overcome `DoesNotExist` error but the error is still there.

I'm using this hack for the gateway login

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from business_accounts.models.my_user import MyUser


class UrlGatewayLogin(View):

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        page_group = kwargs.get('page_group')
        token = request.GET.get('token')
        user = MyUser.objects.get(token=token)
        user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
        login(request, user)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard', args=(page_group, )))
```

Is DRF token unique per user, and how can I generate token in django and use it for my gateway?

Comment: Take a look at this JWT https://thinkster.io/tutorials/django-json-api/authentication

Comment: This is nice, but I've tried to do that, I have JWT setup-ed, the problem is that this is focused on API, and I'm trying to build this for standard django

Answer (score -1):

You need to install Django-Rest-Framework and enable TokenAuthentication in the settings.

First you have to write the a serializer for your User Model, and then create an api view with the serialized data for token authentication.

For example (You can also use username instead of email):
In your users/api/serializers.py file:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.compat import authenticate

from ..models import User


class AuthTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(label=_("Email Address"))
    password = serializers.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        trim_whitespace=False
    )

    def validate(self, data):
        email = data.get('email')
        password = data.get('password')

        if email and password:
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

            if user:
                if not user.is_active:
                    msg = _('User account is deactivated.')
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
            else:
                msg = _('Unable to log in with provided credentials.')
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            msg = _('Must include "email" and "password".')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)

        data['user'] = user
        return data
```

Then in your users/api/views.py file:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from ..models import User


class ObtainAuthToken(APIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({'token': token.key, 'username':user.username})
```

Then in settings, make sure you have token authentication turned on as such:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

In order to return data about the user with that token, you need to write another serializer on the User model including the fields you want to return, for instance:

```
class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username', 'email', 'hobbies', 'language',
            'gender', 'birthday'
        ]
```

And write another api view such as:

```
class UserDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        obj = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.request.user.username)
        return obj
```

The key is to write serializers for your model so that the data can be transported on the Internet.

Comment: This is all ready done, the system does not recognize that token as unique for that user.

Comment: @PetarP Token is like a password. It doesn't have to be unique. You can use the token together with username or email.